# SharePoint Add-in with Nintex Forms

Tags: .net, sharepoint, office365, nintex-workflow

It is possible to create an sharepoint Add-in including Nintex forms and workflow in the O365 environment? How?

Comment: SO strategy: cast the broadest net possible...

Comment: Nintex offers an O365 version of their workflows and forms. https://www.nintex.com

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make this work is to create a server on AWS or Azure that encloses the Nintex platform and exposes various features with secure web services.  Secure those web services with Azure Active Directory and then call those web services from Office 365 or SharePoint Add-ins -- accessing Nintex indirectly.